# Error doing various calls with retrofit in the same model with different variables

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm working with retrofit and I have some problem that I don't know how can I fix it. I have two methods to call my api. One is working fine that is method smsPincodeCheck.

My problem is right now when I try to use another api call. When I try to add isValidPincode any of the two methods are working.

I think that the problem must be in my model class, because when I add the new constructor with three variables and @SerializedName("pincode") don't work any of the two calls.

smsPincodeCheck send to the server two variables
isValidPincode send to the server three variables

To can used it, I've created two constructores in the model, one to can use it with two variables and another one with three. I'm suspecting that the problem could be in this place, but I'm not sure how can fix it.

Some help will be appreciate.

Interface:

```
 @POST("api/check")
    Call<SMSPinCode> smsPincodeCheck(@Body User user);

    @POST("api/check/code")
    Call<ResponseSMS> isValidPincode(@Body User user);
```

Model:

```
    @Expose
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("phoneNumber")
    private String telephone;
    @SerializedName("pincode")
    private String pincode;



 public User(String phone, String email){
        this.telephone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public User(String phone, String email, String pincode){
        this.telephone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

//Getter and setters
```

My Two methods:
1) Call isValidPincode:

```
 User user = new User("34649375362", "m@m.m", "50878");
        Call<ResponseSMS> call = apiService.isValidPincode(user);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseSMS>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseSMS> call, Response<ResponseSMS> response) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Pincode Check: " + response.code());
                }
                if (response.code() == 400) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "400", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Pincode Check: " + response.code());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseSMS> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, call.request().body().toString());
                Log.i(TAG, t.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

2) smsPinCodeCheck:

```
 user = new User("34649375362", "m@m.m");
        Call<ResponseSMS> call = apiService.smsPincodeCheck(user);
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterThreeActivity.this, "", getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseSMS>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseSMS> call, Response<ResponseSMS> response) {
                if(response.isSuccess()){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivity.this, "200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Pincode Check: " + response.code());
                }

                if(response.code() == 401){
                    sendSMS();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Pincode Check: " + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseSMS> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivity.this, "Failure check sms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You're taking about `isValidPincode` and `sendSmsCode` but in the example your using `smsPincodeCheck`. Which one is not working and what is the error.

Comment: Could you provide more details about "any of the two methods are working"? Do you have logs from retrofit or any of the request are called?

Comment: Hi @Uday, sorry, I fix the mistake in my question. Is not working isValidPincode when i add a new constructor in the model and the tag      @SerializedName("pincode")

Comment: Hi @Szwed, I don't have any log. I only know that when I add the new constructor in the model and @SerializedName("pincode")  to can use isValidPincode any of both methods work

Comment: I've updated my questions. Hope that know will be clear my question

Comment: But where is the problem? Do you have compilation error or app crash? Please provide compilation error or stacktrace (when you have app crash)

Comment: No, the app don't crash. The problem is that the code never go throught onResponse or onFailure in the isValidPincode method

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging in your retrofit api. It'll log everything that its sending to the server and the response.

```
private void enableLogging(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
    if (builder != null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        // set your desired log level
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        // Retrofit2 okhttp client is now a builder
        builder.addInterceptor(logging);
    }
}
```

That way you can debug what is being sent to the server and what is missing.

For more details: [Retrofit Logging](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses)

Its not really an answer but this can help you out.

Comment: Hi @Uday. I've added your login and I think that I'm sending this json, but not sure why::: 01-03 15:38:43.718 7239-7645/com.buzinger.loycus.commerce D/OkHttp: {"phoneNumber":"34649375362","email":"m@m.m","pincode":"50878","commerceType":0,"businesSubCategory":0,"businesCategory":0,"active":false,"typeAddress":0}

Comment: I'm only adding three elements in the json

Comment: @S.P. You've added only three elements but during serialization all of the fields are serialized (when you don't assign values the default values for Java are used)

Answer (score 0):

I've read your comments and I think that your code is working fine but you have problem with your server (probably you have wrong params or something). 
You have this log from retrofit:
 `{"phoneNumber":"34649375362","email":"m@m.m","pincode":"5087‌​8","commerceType":0,‌​"businesSubCategory"‌​:0,"businesCategory"‌​:0,"active":false,"t‌​ypeAddress":0}`

This json object corresponds to this object `User user = new User("34649375362", "m@m.m", "50878");`

If you have this log that mean your request was sent to server, but in your onResponse you don't have 100% cases coverage, for example you don't have any action for 404 response.

Please do something like this and check if last log was printed in logcat:

```
if (response.isSuccess()) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "Pincode Check: " + response.code());
    } else if (response.code() == 400) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "400", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "Pincode Check: " + response.code());
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Unexpected error: " + response.code());
    }
```